# Batch to rename unknown folder name to particular name

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

I have a folder named `Results`

inside that results folder a sub folder called `Result*****`

"*" = some random numbers

i donno what will be those random number its keep changing and random..

i want to rename that sub folder from `Result****` to `marks` or anything particular name.

i tried,

```
ren "Result*" "marks"
```

it doesn't works. say no such directory found. Am stuck here donno how to rename that random ending unknown folder to a particular name.

Comment: What does "donno" mean??

Answer (score 1):

In the Windows command prompt, you use the `MOVE` command to rename folders.

So, `Move "Result*" "marks"` should work.

Comment: @Techie , The actual file name was not Result* , star means a random numbers like date and time..it varies.. So, the move command which u says was not works.

Comment: I know what a wildcard is. ;)     If you have a folder named "Result3454544" then the command `Move "Result*" "Marks"` will rename `Result3454544` it to `Marks`.  It works fine here for me, so what actually happens when you attempt to use the command?  Do you get an error?  Which error? Note: if you have more than one folder that matches the wildcard filter (ie: "Result12345" and "Result98765"), then there's no way for Move to be able to discern which you are talking about, and as such will only affect the first matching folder it encounters).